# PHP hits counter

Tags: php, counter

Im having a problem with a php script. I want to make it work so when  under 5 hits it shows a locked button and greater than 5 hits it shows a unlocked button.

```
<?
 if($hits < 5){
    ?>
   <div id="status-button-locked"></div>

    <?  
  }
  ?>

<?

 if($hits > 5){
    ?>
   <div id="status-button-unlocked"></div>

    <?  
  }
  ?>
```

I have tried the code above but it didn't work, when it is greater than 5 it just wont show anything.

Comment: What is your css code?

Comment: @BeatAlex Seriously, what CSS has to do with it?

Comment: @DavidJashi He wants a locked/unlocked button, it could have been his css code being wrong when the ID was being called.

Comment: @BeatAlex read answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't show anything, when 5 hits exactly. Try:

```
<?
 if($hits < 5){
    ?>
   <div id="status-button-locked"></div>
    <?  
  } else {
  ?>
   <div id="status-button-unlocked"></div>
  <?  
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like David said it now doesn't react when it hits exactly 5.

Try this:

```
<?php
  if($hits >= 5){  // this part happens if $hits is 5 or higher.
?>
   <div id="status-button-unlocked"></div>
<?php 
  } else {
?>
   <div id="status-button-locked"></div>    
<?php 
  } 
?>
```

this way you handle errors like when $hits is empty.

Comment: thanks for making it clear. I just didn't know where to put the else condition, now it works :D